# What scala version Intellij Idea scala plugin uses?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, annotations, intellij-plugin

I have en error with java annotation on scala enums. This scala bug seems to be [fixed](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2764), but Inteliij Idea shows an error. So how I can ensure that intellij Idea scala plugin uses actual scala version?

Answer (score 10):

You can check the Scala compiler and language level of your project under your project options from `File > Project Structure... > Modules > Scala`

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if this has been updated by IntelliJ (currently on `2020.02` version) or not, but it was under:

`File > Project Structure > Platform Settings (left tab) > Global Libraries > Scala version"`