# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps in Spark job with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, version, incompatibility

Full error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object;
>           at org.spark_module.SparkModule$.main(SparkModule.scala:62)
>           at org.spark_module.SparkModule.main(SparkModule.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

When I compile and run the code in IntelliJ, it executes fine all the way through. The error shows when I submit the .jar as a spark job (runtime).

Line 62 contains: `for ((elem, i) <- args.zipWithIndex)`. I commented out the rest of the code to be sure, and the error kept showing on that line.

At first I thought it was `zipWithIndex`'s fault. Then I changed it for `for (elem <- args)` and guess what, the error still showed. Is the `for` causing this?

Google searching always points to Scala versions incompatibility between version used to compile and version used on runtime but I can't figure out a solution.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363409/what-scala-version-intellij-idea-scala-plugin-uses) to check Scala version used by IntelliJ and here is everything Scala-related under *Modules > Scala*:

[image]

Then I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2902449/4770813) to check the run-time version of Scala and the output is:

> (file:/C:/Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.11/1a0634714a956c1aae9abefc83acaf6d4eabfa7d/scala-library-2.12.11.jar
>   )

Versions seem to match...

This is my **gradle.build** (includes `fatJar` task)

```
group 'org.spark_module'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

idea {
    project {
        jdkName = '1.8'
        languageLevel = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.12.11'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.12'//, version: '2.4.5'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.12'//, version: '2.4.5'
    implementation group: 'com.datastax.spark', name: 'spark-cassandra-connector_2.12', version: '2.5.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-mllib_2.12', version: '2.4.5'
    implementation group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
    implementation group: 'org.scalaj', name: 'scalaj-http_2.12', version: '2.4.2'
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    zip64 true
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    } {
        exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
    }

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.spark_module.SparkModule'
    }

    with jar
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.guava:guava:12.0.1'
    }
}

compileScala.targetCompatibility = "1.8"
compileScala.sourceCompatibility = "1.8"

jar {
    zip64 true
    getArchiveFileName()
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.spark_module.SparkModule'
    }

    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA'

}
```

To build the (fat) jar:

```
gradlew fatJar
```

in IntelliJ's terminal.

To run the job:

```
spark-submit.cmd .\SparkModule-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

in Windows PowerShell.

Thank you

EDIT:

**spark-submit.cmd** and **spark-shell.cmd** both show Scala version **2.11.12**, so yes, they differ from the one I am using in IntelliJ (**2.12.11**). The problem is, in [Spark's download page](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html), there is only one [Spark distribution for Scala 2.12](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-2.4.5/spark-2.4.5-bin-without-hadoop-scala-2.12.tgz) and it comes without Hadoop; does it mean I have to downgrade from 2.12 to 2.11 in my **gradle.build**?

Comment: you can try specify scala version un gradle build file using `compile` keyword, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44374472/gradle-scala-plugin-how-to-specify-scala-version

Comment: Yes exactly try that, try to change scala version in your gradle.build file

Comment: @Chema but isn't there a way to keep Scala 2.12? a Spark (with Hadoop) dist for Scala 2.12?

Comment: Indeed, it is recommended in 2.4.5 spark version to use 2.12 scala version, and 2.11 is deprecated, have you tried to run your code with 2.11 scala version? I would like to know.

Comment: @Chema, it worked with 2.11, I'm trying to make it work the other way around (with 2.12)

Comment: Your code run Great! I updated my answer with some notes!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops

Answer (score 4):

I would try `spark-submit --version` to know what `scala version` is using `spark`

With `spark-submit --version` I get this information

```
[cloudera@quickstart scala-programming-for-data-science]$ spark-submit --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0.cloudera4
      /_/
                        
Using Scala version 2.11.8, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_202
Branch HEAD
Compiled by user jenkins on 2018-09-27T02:42:51Z
Revision 0ef0912caaab3f2636b98371eb29adb42978c595
Url git://github.mtv.cloudera.com/CDH/spark.git
Type --help for more information.
```

from the `spark-shell` you could try this to know the `scala version`

```
scala> util.Properties.versionString
res3: String = version 2.11.8
```

The `OS` could be using other `scala version`, in my case as you can see `spark scala version` and `OS scala version` are different

```
[cloudera@quickstart scala-programming-for-data-science]$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.12.8 -- Copyright 2002-2018, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.
```

**Note**
**From O'Really Learning Spark** *"Holden Karau, Andy Konwinski,Patrick Wendell & Matei Zaharia"*

**Dependency Conflicts**

One occasionally disruptive issue is dealing with `dependency conflicts` in cases where
a user application and `Spark` itself both depend on the same library. This comes up
relatively rarely, but when it does, it can be vexing for users. Typically, this will manifest
itself when a `NoSuchMethodError`, a `ClassNotFoundException`, or some other
`JVM exception` related to class loading is thrown during the execution of a `Spark` job.
There are two solutions to this problem. The first is to modify your application to
depend on the same version of the `third-party library` that `Spark` does. The second is
to modify the packaging of your application using a procedure that is often called
“**shading**.” The `Maven` build tool supports shading through advanced configuration
of the plug-in shown in Example 7-5 (in fact, the **shading** capability is why the plugin
is named `maven-shade-plugin`). **Shading** allows you to make a second copy of the
conflicting package under a different namespace and rewrites your application’s code
to use the renamed version. This somewhat `brute-force` technique is quite effective at
resolving runtime `dependency conflicts`. For specific instructions on how to **shade**
dependencies, see the documentation for your build tool.